# How to capture a CompositionEvent outside of a textarea or input?

Tags: javascript, input

(I've asked something similar in the past, before discovering `CompositionEvent`.)
With Chrome under Linux, we can use the compose key to enter e.g. ä or ç.

If I use the compose key inside a textarea or input, I get `CompositionEvent`s from `addEventListener("compositionstart",...)`.

But how to I capture composition events when a textarea or input is not focused?
(If I do e.g. `window.addEventListener("compositionstart",...)`, the handler isn't called.)

Now google docs can capture these events in its wysiwyg editor, so it appears possible, but how? (Essentially I want to capture input text, outside of an input or textarea, *after* the compose session has finished, if the compose key is being used, that is, I want to get the ä, or ç, not the individual key events.)

Comment: In the wysiwyg they certainly use either a `<div contenteditable>` or an hidden input.

Comment: seems not supported, like `focus` event, not bubbling...

Answer (score 0):

It seams like you need an input element or alike that is focused to make these events happen. I don't know if this could work in your context, but here I have an event listener for the keydown event (happens before the letter i typed) on body. It will focus an input element that is rendered outside the view port (well, that is up to you, you could also type white on white). With the input in focus I can now type the composition sequence and the composition event will be fired.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
input.focus();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  input.focus();
},true);

document.body.addEventListener("compositionstart", e => {
  console.log(`${e.type}: ${e.data}`);
});

document.body.addEventListener("compositionupdate", e => {
  console.log(`${e.type}: ${e.data}`);
});

document.body.addEventListener("compositionend", e => {
  console.log(`${e.type}: ${e.data}`);
  e.target.value = '';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" style="position: absolute;top: -100px;">
```

Comment: This does not trigger the composition event listener on the first keypress, only subsequent keypresses